# In Android Appium is there any method to scroll to the end of the screen. The elements at the end of the screen is dynamic

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, appium, appium-android

In the Android Native View I need to scroll to the end of the screen where the elements are dynamic. Sometimes there will be a list of 10 elements and sometimes there will be list of 20 very dynamic elements. I need to scroll to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Welcome! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Comment: Checkout this will help you to resolve your issue.

 https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-do-scroll-action-till-the-particular-element-is-present-or-not/6003